# Is it possible to check if a specific process is sleeping or running?

Tags: bash, command-line, process

I've created the following script on Ubuntu that can **pause** and **start** a specific process:

```
#!/bin/bash

loopProcess () {
   COUNTER=0
   while [  true ]; do
      echo $COUNTER
      sleep 1
      let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
   done
}

loopProcess &
pidLoopProcess="$!"

while [  true ]; do
   read -p "" state
   if [ "$state" == 'a'  ]; then
      echo "Process is running"
      kill -CONT "$pidLoopProcess"
   elif [ "$state" == 'b'  ]; then
      echo "Process is sleeping"
      kill -STOP "$pidLoopProcess"
   fi  
done
```

Demonstration of how it works:

[image]

I'd like to know if it's possible to check when a specific process is **running** or **sleeping** using the command line. The pseudocode would be something like this:

```
if [ "$(StatePID $pidLoopProcess)" == 'sleeping'  ]; then
    ## do something
fi
```

I know that with this script I could just declare some global variables and use them as flags... But **I want to know if there's a command line tool that does that for me. Is there? Is it possible?**

Comment: using the `ps` command?

Comment: What operating system are you using? And do you need solutions for that operating system only or do solutions need to be portable?

Comment: @terdon I'm using Ubuntu... I've edited the tags of my question to specify that.

Comment: Thanks, but please don't use tags for that. OS tags should only be used when the question is asking about something _specific_ to that OS and not to indicate that you are just using that OS. By the way, your `pidLoopProcess=$(echo $!)` would be better written as `pidLoopProcess=$!`. Also, be aware that since you are using `sleep` here, your status will very often be `S` since the `ps` will most likely catch the `loopProcess` while the `sleep` is being run.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Linux, you can use this to get the status of a process with a given PID:

```
ps -o stat= $pid
```

That returns `T` when a process is stopped. So, assuming you are on a Linux system, you could do something like this:

```
if [ "$(ps -o stat= $pid)" = "T" ]; then 
    echo stopped
else 
    echo not stopped
fi
```

A full list of process state codes is given in `man ps`:

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
       Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers
       (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of a process:

               D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
               I    Idle kernel thread
               R    running or runnable (on run queue)
               S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
               T    stopped by job control signal
               t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
               W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
               X    dead (should never be seen)
               Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent

   For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be
   displayed:

           <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
           N    low-priority (nice to other users)
           L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
           s    is a session leader
           l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
           +    is in the foreground process group
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!! But in the context of my script the states are `T+` and `S+` because it's a foreground process..

Comment: perhaps `case ... in (T*)...` then?

Comment: @RafaelMuynarsk well, you were running it in the background in your example. Also, no, the comparison will work with `=`. In fact, `=` is more portable than `==` which is a bashism. See `help test` which doesn't even mention the `==`.